# What is the meaning of the phrase "going from betting on the river to drawing dead"?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

[Source](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Drawing_Dead)

> “Bring us the girl, and wipe away the debt.” As plans go, I'd seen worse -- except this girl was already gone. Monument Island's a damn ghost town. Seems like they evacuated her when they heard I was here. An old friend told me Comstock spirited her off to that fortress of his. As a one-man job, **this just went from bettin' on the river to...drawing dead**.

I couldn't find the meaning in any online dictionary. Where does the phrase come from and what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like colorful use of poker terms.

[River](https://www.pokernews.com/pokerterms/river.htm) - the last card in a hand

[Drawing dead](https://www.texasholdem-king.com/poker-terms/drawing-dead/) - no potential chance to win the hand any more

So the sense seems to be going from a chance to win to ... no chance to win.